# How to Scrape data from list

Tags: web-scraping, data-science

I'm trying to scrape data from [https://www.idealista.com/maps/madrid-madrid/][1]

I'm not getting the whole content of the page. I used BeautifulSoup python library. what I need is the list of the streets available on the webpage.

I'm a beginner to web scraping, Can anyone help on how to proceed or which libraries to use to get this done?

Comment: When I looked it just now it appears that they have anti-scrape functionality on their page, so I am not going to help circumvent that.

Comment: There are no such thing as "anti-scrape" IMO. I didn't take a look at what makes it "unscrapable" and didn't looked at their terms of use... EDIT: actually looked at their terms of use, they explicitly tell NOT to`[...] use automatic mechanisms to copy or extract our content [...]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.